# Boost_program_option is not found during the cmake step

Tags: boost, cmake

I am installing a bioinformatic tool named SuperDCA in a new conda environment. However, I get an error in the cmake step. It indicates:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /mnt/d/conda/superdca/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /mnt/d/conda/superdca/bin/CC - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Setting build type to "Release" since none was specified by user.
SUPERDCA_DEPENDENCIES setup: check for Boost
CMake Error at /mnt/d/conda/superdca/lib/cmake/Boost-1.80.0/BoostConfig.cmake:141 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /mnt/d/conda/superdca/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.80.0/boost_program_options-config.cmake

  but it set boost_program_options_FOUND to FALSE so package
  "boost_program_options" is considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by
  package:

  No suitable build variant has been found.

  The following variants have been tried and rejected:

  * libboost_program_options.so.1.80.0 (shared, Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON)

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /mnt/d/conda/superdca/lib/cmake/Boost-1.80.0/BoostConfig.cmake:262 (boost_find_component)
  /mnt/d/conda/superdca/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:594 (find_package)
  externals/boost.cmake:25 (find_package)
  externals/CMakeLists.txt:14 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/mnt/d/download/SuperDCA/SuperDCA/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Since it says `it set boost_program_options_FOUND to FALSE`, should I set it to TRUE?

The package versions are:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
boost-cpp                 1.80.0               h75c5d50_0    conda-forge
cmake                     3.24.1               h5432695_0    conda-forge
```

Answer (score 1):

The clue is here:

```
* libboost_program_options.so.1.80.0 (shared, Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON)
```

Presumbly your Conda environment has only shared libraries for Boost in `$CONDA_PREFIX/lib`, and not static ones.  For some reason, the software you're trying to build has set `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` to require static linking.  Without knowing why that is, there are two possible solutions:

1. Find where `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` is set, and remove it.
2. Find a Boost package which contains static libraries.  This may be fairly uncommon on Linux, where shared libraries are used most of the time.